# calculating in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

What I have done so far:

```
import datetime
   distance_tobecovered = float(input("Please enter a number for the startime = input("Please input the time for the alarm in format HH:")
    fixed_charge = 3.5
    perkilo_charge = 2.1 * distance_tobecovered
    valueforall = fixed_charge + perkilo_charge
    v = valueforall + (2 * distance_tobecovered * 0.99
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter the time as: 10:24, this: datetime.datetime.strptime(startime,"%H:%M") will work.   If you enter the time as 10, your example will work.

All depends on how you define your time input.

Also, your comparison seems off.

```
import datetime
distance_tobecovered = float(input("Please enter a number for the distance: "))
startime = input("Please input the time for the alarm in format HH:MM :")
fixed_charge = 3.5
perkilo_charge = 2.1 * distance_tobecovered
valueforall = fixed_charge + perkilo_charge
v = valueforall + (2 * distance_tobecovered * 0.99)

input_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(startime, "%H:%M")

if ((input_time.hour>=23) or (input_time.hour < 6)):
    print("night or early morning")
    print(v)#does some calculation
else:
    print("day")
    print("#does some calculation ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `input_time.hour` to integers. There is no integer N such that `23 <= N <= 6`, so the condition in your `elif` statement will never be true. You should simply replace the `elif` statement with an `else`.